# Dealing with gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When I added an 'edit' column to a GridView, I got this error:

The GridView 'RegisteredList' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The GridView fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170571/the-gridview-fired-event-rowediting-which-wasnt-handled)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the event RowEditing.  In the markup:

```
<asp:GridView id="RegisteredList" runat="Server" 
OnRowEditing="RegisteredList_RowEditing"/>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void RegisteredList_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```